# PHP copy mysql_fetch_array to a new one

Tags: php, arrays, copy

how can i copy an array that's come from mysql_fetch_array to an other one

**for example:**

```
 mysql connection--------->
    $array = array();
    $row= mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

I want to copy the array $row to the new one $array

i tried with $row = $array but it didn't work when im dumping it the new array is empty.

Comment: You have it backward.  `$array = $row;`

Comment: `$row = $array` copies $array into $row. Did you mean the other way around (i.e. `$array = $row`)?

Comment: or `$array = $row= mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: copy to override or to append??

Comment: Sorry to say, but IMO you should try things first before asking.

Comment: Or why don't you just assing directly $array = mysql_fetch_array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: +1, I think you're actually the only one who perfectly understood what the OP meant.

Comment: Thanks i did it wrong when i use to call first $row the $array thanks agine.

Comment: Missing a `$` on your `$array` variable.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `array_merge($array,$row)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$array = $row;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$array = $row;
```

Instead of:

```
$row = $array;
```